# biblatex, hyperref and punctuation issue

Tags: spacing, biblatex, hyperref, punctuation, italic-correction

And a little bit more biblatex stuff: I've noticed that, when using hyperref, there is an issue in form of an ugly space between the citation and the punctuation (be it comma or period). Please, take a look at the following example code:

```
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@book{JSmith,
author = {Smith, John},
title = {A book of}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authortitle]{biblatex}
\bibliography{mybib.bib}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
Test~\cite*{JSmith}. Test~\footcite{JSmith}

Test~\emph{A book of}. Test\footnote{Smith, \emph{A book of}.}
\end{document}
```

Any ideas?

---

**EDIT**: Just to let you know, I posted the question here too: http://groups.google.com/group/comp.text.tex/browse_thread/thread/908bd4ff3f8633b2#

I'll keep them both in sync.

---

**EDIT 2**: Heiko Oberdiek kindly provided the answer "why" this happens (on comp.text.tex):

> `\cite*` uses `\emph` and `\emph` suppresses
>   the italic correction at the  right
>   end if a comma or period follows
>   (`\nocorrlist`). However adding a  link
>   implies that whatits are added in
>   between (in case of hpdftex.def  there
>   are two whatits, the end of the link
>   and restoring the color.  Therefore
>   the period is hidden from `\emph`.
>
> Example without **biblatex**:
>
> ```
> \documentclass[12pt]{article} 
> \showboxdepth=\maxdimen 
> \showboxbreadth=\maxdimen 
> \usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref} 
>
> \begin{document} 
> \section{Foo}\label{sec:foo} 
> \huge 
> \noindent 
> Test~\emph{Smith of}.\\ 
> Test~\hyperref[sec:foo]{\emph{Smith of}}. 
>
> \tracingonline=1 
> \showlists 
> \end{document}
> ```

---

**EDIT 3**: Ulrike Fischer proposed a local fix:

> You can locally reset the definition
>   of `\citetitle` (if you do it  globally
>   it will perhaps remove the italic
>   correction also in places  where you
>   want it):
>
> `{\DeclareFieldFormat{citetitle}{\mkbibemph{#1\nocorr}}\cite*{JSmith}.}`

Comment: Does this still happen if you include all the mandatory fields for the book class? (i.e. publisher and year, I think...)

Comment: author, title, year/date. Yes, it happens no matter what fields are present.

Comment: In case somebody on the comp.text.tex group gives you a good enough answer before anybody here can, would you mind posting it here as well? We try to have complete answers to the questions here instead of simply linking to them, in case those links become dead one day.

Comment: No worries, I'll sync them: everything that comes in there will arrive here too and vice versa.

Answer (score 3):

I got a response from Philipp Lehman on comp.text.tex:

> meho_r wrote:
>
> > So, what can we (users) do about it?
>
> Not much, I'm afraid, short of manual
>   workarounds.
>
> `\emph` and friends use a rather simple
>   look-ahead routine to decide  whether
>   or not italic correction is required.
>   A simple `\relax` will  confuse it.
>   Compare this:
>
> ```
> \emph{of}.  
> \emph{of}\relax.
> ```
>
> Once the italic correction has been
>   added, all you can do is remove it 
>   manually. It's a `\kern`, hence you may
>   use `\unkern`:
>
> ```
> \emph{of}\relax\unkern.
> ```
>
> In fact, **biblatex** does precisely that
>   automatically. If you comment  out
>   **hyperref**, your example will be fine.
>
> Unfortunately, this won't work if the
>   text in italics is a link while  the
>   punctuation is not part of the link:
>
> ```
> \href{http://www.foobar.com}{\emph{of}}.
> \href{http://www.foobar.com}{\emph{of}}\unkern.
> ```
>
> The `\unkern` kicks in too late. It
>   would need to move inside the link 
>   group to do its job:
>
> ```
> \href{http://www.foobar.com}{\emph{of}\unkern}.
> ```
>
> Trouble is: you need to remove the
>   italic correction inside the link 
>   group but you don't know if you need
>   to remove it until after the  link.
>
> I don't see any way to deal with that
>   automatically. These are  potentially
>   deeply nested structures. There could
>   be dozens of tokens  and multiple
>   groups between the end of the link and
>   the punctuation.
>
> You can either disable links
>   (**hyperref=false**) or set up a special 
>   `\cite` command with a decicated format
>   definition suppressing the  italic
>   correction. So, along the lines of
>   what Ulrike has suggested,  here's my
>   take:
>
> ```
> \DeclareFieldFormat{nocorremph}{\mkbibemph{#1\nocorr}}
> \newrobustcmd{\nccite}{%   
> \AtNextCite{\DeclareFieldAlias{citetitle}{nocorremph}}
> \cite}
> ```
>
> Now compare:
>
> ```
> \cite*{JSmith}.
> \nccite*{JSmith}.
> ```
>
> Not nice, but it works.